# Tool for creating portfolio item for Mobile, Tab and desktop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, website-design, designers

I would like to create a nice portfolio item like below. But I'm a developer and no experience with graphic design. But I would like to create portfolio items. i.e. no need to be a professional designer. I just need to learn something to do this task. Could you tell me what kind of tool should I use for it? Do I have any free tools to create such portfolio items very easily?

**tl;dr:** I will have a web site and I would like to create its front screen as portfolio item on mobile, tab, and desktop as below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in Photoshop. The quickest and easiest way for a non-designer might be to buy or find a PSD mockup template, and just fill them with the screen content. Just google "PSD mockup template for tablet phone desktop" to find some.

I'm not affiliated with Adobe, and don't really want to advertise for them, but there are many such good quality PSD templates for sale on the Adobe Stock website.

Other stock image sites also have similar templates.

Comment: I hope where I need to purchase Photoshop for that no? i.e. open a PSD file and etc?

Comment: Well, Photoshop isn't free. Sorry about that.  There is a trial but it doesn't last very long.  You can sometimes open PSD templates in Krita which is free. I can't guarantee compatibility however.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction.

Comment: could as well buy from any stock image website (shutterstock comes to mind)

Comment: @Luciano I already said that in my answer - "other stock image sites also have similar templates".

Comment: oh sorry, you're right

Comment: @Luciano I've added a space between that sentence and the paragraph above to make it more noticeable.